# Liquid Layout: 100% max-width img not applied - why?

Tags: css, liquid-layout

I'm totally new to this liquid layout stuff. I've notice, as most of us, that while most of my layout components "liquify", images, unfortunately, don't.

So I'm trying to use the `max-width: 100%` on images as suggested on several places.

However, and despite the definition of `max-width` and `min-height` of the img **container**, the **img** don't scale.

If you see it on a wide resolution, you would notice that the "kid image", for example, don't scale.

Any clue about what could the issue be, why does that image not scale?

**Test case:**

Browsers: *Firefox 15.0* / *Chrome 21.0*

IOS: *MAC OS X Lion - 10.7.3*

Resolution: *1920x1200*

**What I get:**
I get an image that doesn't scale until the end of it's container.
The img width won't fit the `article` element that contains it.
[image: image should scale as the arrow indicates]

**What I do expect:**
I expect the image to enlarge, until it reaches the end it's container. 
Visually, I'm expecting the image to be as wide as the paragraph immediately below, in a way that, the right side of the image stays vertically aligned with the right side of the paragraph below.

Comment: It works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LdAYk/ Can you produce a demo or clarify what your problem is?

Comment: unfortunately not now. So perhaps is something that is overwriting on the css... any guess about what could it be ?

Comment: Use a debugger (Chrome developer tools, Firebug, etc.) and you can find out for yourself.

Comment: I use it. I found nothing. :/ I will try to provide a demo link.

Comment: @WesleyMurch updated with a link.

Comment: JSFiddle uses a CSS normalization to strip any browser-specific default styling which may account for the differences in styling. Have you applied a CSS reset prior to your custom CSS?

Comment: I normally don't apply a CSS reset on my layouts, I tend to apply resets only when I **see** the need for them. I'm trying to figure this out myself...

Comment: Your link works fine for me, please explain ***exactly*** what results you are seeing and what you are expecting to see - you might just not understand what `max-width:100%` is supposed to actually do.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I've tried to properly explain my problem. Question updated.

Comment: Sounds like you just want `width:100%`. The whole point of `max-width` is to *limit* the width of the image so it doesn't extend beyond the boundaries of the container when it is small. However, I don't recommend that as a default, consider images that are meant to be small will be affected.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I've just added an image, so that it stays perfectly clear. So, in order to have that with `max-width`, we need to upload a bigger image, and the max-width will then tell us that, my big image will narrow until the container limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `max-width` does.

`max-width:100%` means "the maximum width this element can be is 100% of it's container". Anything that's naturally smaller will not be affected. That's what you have now and it's working properly. If you used `max-width:800px`, it would mean "never let this image be more than 800px wide", it wouldn't force an 800px width, that's what `width` is for.

`width:100%` means "this element should always be 100% width of it's container". Anything that would normally be smaller must now take up the entire width. Anything bigger will shrink to the container's width.

For your case, just use `width:100%` and size your actual images to fit the actual maximum (and pick a reasonable maximum width for the container). Images usually look better when scaled down than scaled up, but when optimizing for mobile devices you might want to do the opposite.

The reason you usually see `max-width:100%` as a default style is so images don't extend beyond their containers and break the layout, since images are usually sized naturally by their actual width.

Comment: Why can't I just upload a bigger image, and use max-width: 100% - avoiding with this that small images (like the faces above on that same layout), to grow exaggeratedly ? Why should I prefer width: 100% over max-width: 100% ?

Comment: You don't want to use `width:100%` as a default, just for those 3 images (see my last line), and yes you can upload a bigger image, that's one of the things I suggested. `"Why should I prefer width: 100% over max-width: 100% ?"` because you seem to want those images to be 100% width at all times. Please remember, these are two totally separate properties that do different things.

Comment: I would than take that approach. Yes, I knew it was, and I never told I preferred the other way around. But I wasn't getting how should that be done (the "upload a bigger image" was missing). :)

Comment: I think if you take a minute to understand what `max`imum means it will be clear to you. If the image is *too* big, it will shrink down. If not, then it won't do anything. It's like me saying: "Please get me max 6 beers", 4 or none would be technically correct. If I wanted 6, I'd just say to get me 6.

Comment: I now understand the max-width:100% necessity. I also understand the width:100% need we may have. Please correct me if I'm wrong. if I wished to have have that image always, as big as the container, I may give it a width property and it will scale up. Issues with this: scape up is not that good, small images what we don't want to scale may be affected. I can also use max-width: 100% and have the same effect for the *most* of the resolutions, if I upload a big enough image to accommodate the hypothetical biggest scenario we wish to cover. Issues: huge image loaded.

Comment: Yeah you have to make a decision. My preference would probably be to use a *reasonable* actual image size, and either: Option 1: `width:100%` or Option 2: `max-width:100%` and center the images in case they are too small naturally.

Comment: I don't know what "DB profiler still on" means. I suppose db stands for database, but profiler being on, I don't get.We will opt for option max-width:100%. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: "DB profiler still on" means look at the bottom of your page: "Relatorio Resumido de Profiling..." Not related, just letting you know since you've pasted a link to your site and might not want that information public.

Answer (score 0):

For me your images are scaling with resizing the viewport. But instead of max-width, use just width. But it works with both.

Comment: Sorry to ask but, have you resize the viewport, but staying on the same resolution or, have you raise up your resolution, and see it there ? I must notice that I'm testing this on Firefox 14.0.1 btw.

Comment: I have no idea why someone should change his resolution settings while surfing a webpage, but I have tried to change my resolution back and forth with your page opened at I don't see scaling problems

Comment: You can't just replace `max-width` with `width` or it will blow up smaller images to be way too big. Is that what the OP wants? Might be so, because I have no idea what the problem could be. @MEM: Please explain ***exactly*** what results you are seeing and what you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understaning is consern if i have a image of 300px width (means image is created as such with width of 300px)

Now this image is inside a div whose width is say 40% of its container (which is body in my case)

if i give my img widht:100% it means say if my div is of 500px (40% of whole body width) width my image will be of same width as its container (div in my case).

if i give img max-width:100% it means my image's maximum width will always be 300px (in other word what ever its original width is when it got created)

max-widht really helps in maintaining px clarity of your image